# How can I use nginx on my local machine to redirect cnn.com to a 404?

Tags: macos, nginx

I want to redirect cnn.com on my local Mac OSX to a 404 page. Here is what I have currently, but cnn.com still works (and redirects to edition.cnn.com):

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 cnn.com
```

/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
# some config
http {
    # some config
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name cnn.com;
        location / {
            return 404;
        }
    }
    # more config
}
# more config
```

Or, is there a better way to accomplish this using another service?

Comment: Don't you need a `server` block?

Comment: @Rahul thank you, messed up inputting the file :/, just updated.

Comment: I can't imagine the usecase where a httpreverseproxy should be used for blocking outgoing connections. 
 
What you are trying to accomplish is something as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Content-control_software
 
Whereas nginx is used for the complete opposite a reverseproxy:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy
 
You should look into:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201813

Comment: I guess, you should also add `www.cnn.com`